# Windows Server 2008 R2 Speech Recognition

Tags: windows

I need to deploy a speech recognition sever side application on Windows Server 2008 R2.

However the application fails due to the absence of Speech Recognition services on this Windows version (works fine in Win 7 / 8 / 10).

How can I add/enable Speech Recognition services to Windows 2008 R2?

Comment: I think you need to install this on the server - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224

Comment: Thanks, however installing the above didn't fix the issue. I have also tried to install Desktop Experience, and manually import sapi dlls from Windows 7, still without success.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49038869/12861